# How to configure GitLab to use external git repository on a remote server

Tags: git, external, gitlab

We have been developing several projects on git (with a remote git repository on ServerA, for example). Now we have installed GitLab on ServerB and want to configure it to use the git on ServerA (because ServerA is carefully maintained, backed up, and ...). Is there anyway to do the job?
Another problem is that access to each repository on ServerA is set for users (at no, read, or write access). How can those accesses by applied to ServerB?

Comment: Can ServerB access ServerA repositories folder through a networkshared path?

Comment: Yes, ServerA repository folders can be shared with ServerB as networkshared path. By the way, I updated the question with some notes about access control :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, if the repositories can be access through a network path from ServerB to ServerA, all you need to do is to report that path in [the GitLab config.yml](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/236741008ed82b77e3e4357e07060f7764d1d21a/config/gitlab.yml.example#L262)

```
# REPOS_PATH MUST NOT BE A SYMLINK!!!
repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
```

In that case, the GitLab process should have full read/write access to those repos, as the users won't have a direct access to them anymore.

Comment: Where can I find this config.yml? I've seen reference to this everywhere but it doesn't seem to exist on my system using `gitlab_7.6.1-omnibus`. I am guessing this file is only available to those installing from source. Is there any way to set that after an Omnibus install? The only setting file I am aware of is `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

Comment: @PolyMesh that config.yml is at least in the sources: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example. In an omnibus installation, some settings seems to be directly in the rb files, like here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#setting-up-ldap-sign-in

Comment: @PolyMesh as the documentation states: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/gitlab.yml.md: Some of GitLab's features can be customized through gitlab.yml and application.yml (GitLab CI). If you want to change a gitlab.yml setting with omnibus-gitlab, you need to do so via /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb.